# Checking if a set of string in a file are in another file or not using python or bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, search, command-line

Hi I want to check whether a set of words (alphanumeric) contained in one file are in another file containing some set of words.

Like I have a file: f1.txt (20K size)

```
w1
w2
w3
w4
.. //more ids like this
```

Another file f2.txt (120 K size)

```
q1
q2
q3
q4
q5
q6
q7
q8
w2
```

So I want to check "how" many and "which" ids from "f1.txt" are present in "f2.txt"

I want the output to be like:

```
1
w2
```

I know this is easy and can be done using loops. I want to know if we can do this using bash scripting, using "grep" n all. As this is fast, I mainly want to analyze the data.
Python would also do.

Any leads appreciated.

Comment: awk is probably the fastest way to do this (unless you wrote something in C or some other compiled language), although Python would be pretty quick if you used a set for the f1 data. Definitely don't try to do this using a Bash script that parses f1 and uses that data to grep f2, that'd be rather slow, and besides, it's [bad practice to use a shell loop to process text](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> [str.count(sub[, start[, end]])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)
>
> Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring `sub` in the range `[start, end]`. Optional arguments `start` and `end` are interpreted as in slice notation.

```
f1_lines = [line.strip("\n") for line in f1.readlines()]
f2_lines = [line.strip("\n") for line in f2.readlines()]

for w in f1_lines:
    print(w, f2_lines.count(w))
```

Answer (score 3):

since the file is not so big, we can put them in memory (an awk hashtable) to compare:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$0 in a{a[$0]++}
  END{for(x in a)if(a[x])print x, a[x]}' f1 f2
```

It outputs:

```
w2 1
```

(The output is just for example, output format could be easily adjusted.)

```
awk                    # the awk cmd
'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}   # take the first file:f1, save in hashtable a[word]=0
$0 in a{a[$0]++}       # take the 2nd file:f2, if word in a hit, increment
END{                   # after two files are processed, we r about to print
   for(x in a)         # go thru the hashtable
    if(a[x])           # if value>0 (the word shows in f2)
     print x, a[x]}'   # we print the which word(key), and how many times(value) 
f1 f2                  # two input files.
```

Comment: this is not working correctly for my large data set. I shows 2 even for ids not in f2.txt.

Comment: Though it works well for this small file provided  above.